Schedule jupyter notebooks without relying on local system
Is it possible to schedule jupyter notebook that uses one drive files without relying on local system. I have created a shortcut to one drive in my company’s sharepoint and read those files in my jupyter notebook(Notebook reads csv files from onedrive). Im currently scheduling the notebook daily in jupyterlab but this is in my local system and requires my laptop to be turned on and to open jupyterlab daily. Is there a way to schedule it to run without relying on local system?
I tried using power automate but not completely sure if that would help

Please edit your post to make clearer the actual situation. You are using 'scripts' and 'notebooks' interchangeably it seems? Maybe? Python code can go into a notebook cell or cells to be used by the Python kernel. Python code can also go in a Python script that ends in .py extension and you'd point Python at it on the command line with python my_script.py and in the notebook %run myscript.py. Code and scripts are not the same. Can you clarify?

Jupyter can run on headless computers/servers that you then tunnel into. Or you'll have some more flexibility if you convert your notebooks to pure Python code and then run those with a scheduler but some computer/server needs to be turn on somewhere. Whether it uses Python running in Jupyter or Python running directly with your code in a.py file. Who set up the sharepoint? That would be the persons to talk with whether they offer you a server where you can run Python or Jupyter. Because they probably don't want you using just any random server and/or security is involved. See ...

 here.

Thank you for your inputs. I’m using jupyter notebook and the code is in different cells in the notebook. It is a file stored with .ipynb extension. I will try to make my question more clear.

Like I referenced, in general you have more flexibility with an actual Python script, Jupytext can help you in the conversion. However, these days it is less necessary than the past. You can also run the notebooks on the command line with jupytext, papermill, or jupyter nbconvert. So those commands can be made into chron jobs. On the other sider there's schedulers for Jupyter, like discussed here. And as I said, these things are require at least systems that are running ...

 and so there is usually a server or remote cloud instance involved.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Wayne Can you suggest some remote cloud instance that I can use to schedule this so that running local systems support is not needed

This is very much information already available online. See here for example. Or PythonAnywhere, see here. With the latter, you may have an easier time with it as a script. See the section 'Search, and research' in How do I ask a good question?.

Also see here.
